# Why is TF-IDF calculation taking so much time?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, tf-idf

I use the TF-IDF code from [here](https://stevenloria.com/tf-idf/) in my corpus of documents, which is 3 PDF documents, each about 270 pages long.

```
# Calculating the Term Frequency, Inverse Document Frequency score
import os
import math
from textblob import TextBlob as tb

def tf(word, blob):
    return tb(blob).words.count(word) / len(tb(blob).words)

def n_containing(word, bloblist):
    return sum(1 for blob in bloblist if word in tb(blob).words)

def idf(word, bloblist):
    return math.log(len(bloblist) / (1 + n_containing(word, bloblist)))

def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
    return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)




# Stemming the articles
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
port = PorterStemmer()

bloblist = []
doclist = [pdf1, pdf2, pdf3]   # Defined earlier, not showing here as it is not relevant to the question
for doc in doclist:
    bloblist.append(port.stem(str(doc)))




# TF-IDF calculation on the stemmed articles
for index, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
    print("Top words in document {}".format(index + 1))
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in tb(blob).words}
    sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    i=1
    for word, score in sorted_words[:5]:
        print("\tWord "+str(i)+": {}, TF-IDF: {}".format(word, round(score, 5)))
        i+=1
```

The problem is, it just keeps running, without displaying anything beyond `Top words in document 1`. Why is it taking so long to calculate the `scores`? I've kept it running for an hour now, and the code hasn't terminated. Earlier I tried out the code for 50 odd txt files which were much shorter in length (like, 2-3 paragraphs on average), and there it was able to show the TF-IDF scores instantaneously. What's wrong with 3 docs of 270 pages each?

Answer (score 1):

Some things pop up from a cursory glance,
1) Without seeing how the method tb is implemented, it seems however that you are calling `tb(blob)` for each word. Perhaps making an object from whatever `tb(blob)` returns once for each word would speed things up.
2)`nltk` has its own `tfidf` implementation, which would be much more optimized and which could speed things up.
3)You could do your implementation but with `numpy` instead of vanilla python which will definitely speed things up.But even with this, it would be a better idea to cache the results and use them instead of calling a possibly heavy function multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentioned you are calling `tb(blob)` too much; it looks like for a document with N words you call it more than N^2 times. That is always going to be slow. You need to make a change like this:

```py
for index, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
    print("Top words in document {}".format(index + 1))
    # XXX use textblob here just once
    tblob = tb(blob)
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, tblob, bloblist) for word in tblob.words}
    sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    i=1
    for word, score in sorted_words[:5]:
        print("\tWord "+str(i)+": {}, TF-IDF: {}".format(word, round(score, 5)))
        i+=1
```

You will also need to change your tfidf functions so they use the `tblob` instead of calling `tb(blob)` every time.

Comment: I did this, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. The code still keeps running for hours with no output.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you should run a profiler - doesn't seem like you're doing anything that should take that long.